# Vue JS: Looping through object inline attribute

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, object, vue-component

I am new to vue.js so this might be an easy question, but I unfortunatelly didnt come to a result on my own.

So this is the basis of my template:

```
<template v-for="page in $props.data.pageInfo" >
  <div class="overviewItem" :key="page.uid" :data-cat=" **looping through the object to get both cat_id's ** ">
    <div v-for="(cat, index) in page.categories" :key="index" >
      <p v-if="index === 0" class="subtitle">
        {{ cat.title }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

{{ page.categories }} has the following values at the first .overviewItem:

```
[
{
  "cat_id": 1,
  "title": "Kategorie 1"
},
{
  "cat_id": 2,
  "title": "Kategorie 2"
}
]
```

The loop to get the subtitle works perfectly fine, but I cannot find any option on how to loop through this object so that i get the two values of data-cat attribute.

Comment: Remove the `v-if` on the `<p>` which is only allowing the first item to be rendered and put `data-cat` on the loop `<div>`

Comment: I need the data-cat to be outside (on the .overviewItem). Inside I do actually only want the first title to be displayed, that is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map` to generate a new array of just the `cat_id` and then join them together with a space in between:

```
<div
   class="overviewItem"
   :key="page.uid"
   :data-cat="page.categories.map(c => c.cat_id).join(' ')"
>
...
</div>
```